# How to write $A D A^T x$ as $\sum_{j=1}^p A_j D_{jj} A_j^T x$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, a diagonal matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$, and a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$.

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ be

$$
y = ADA^Tx
$$

What is an easy way to see the above is equivalent to the following summation form:

$$
y = \sum_{j=1}^p A_j D_{jj} A_j^T x
$$

Where $A_j$ is the $j$-th column of $A$, and $A_j^T$ is the j-th column of $A$ represented as a row vector.

Comment: It suffices to show $ADA^\top = \sum_{j=1}^p A_j D_{jj} A_j^\top$. One [admittedly cumbersome] way to do this is to check that the corresponding entries of each matrix are the same.

Comment: @angryavian Yeah, I actually did that initially but it's pretty tedious, like you said. I thought there was some obvious intuition that I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the fact that $ADA^Tx=(AD)A^Tx$. Then,

$y=\sum_{j=1}^p (A_j D_{j,j})A^T_jx$

This is a consequence of matrix multiplication being associative, thus $AD$ is the linear combination of the row vectors of $A$ by the column vectors of $D$.

Hope this hint helps.

Comment: I understand the $AD$ part, but I don't understand how $(AD)A^Tx$ can be easily written as that summation.

Comment: Oh nvm, i made this much harder than it needed to be..

Comment: How did you finally solved? Did the hint help? Taking into account that $D$ is diagonal, instead of having $D_{i,j}$ we write $D_{j,j}$. Then the product $AD$ are the columns of $A$, where each $j$-th column is multiplied by the element $D_{j,j}$. The part out of pharentesis $A^Tx$ is easy to follow.

Comment: Basically I had $AD = [D_{11}A_1 \ \ \ D_{22}A_2 \ \ \ \ldots D_{pp}A_p]$ and $A^Tx = [A_1^Tx \ \ \ A_2^Tx \ \ \ \ldots A_p^T x]^T$. So $(AD)A^Tx = D_{11}A_1 A_1^Tx + D_{22}A_2A_2^Tx + \ldots + D_{pp}A_p A_p^T x$. And from this last summation it becomes obvious.